# How to solve these two ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For each one of them $y=y\left(x\right)$

$\text{(1) }\left(2x-y^{2}\right)\cdot y'=2y$

$\text{(2) }\left(x^{3}+e^{y}\right)\cdot y'=3x^{2}$

I suspect they might be "of the same kind".

What I tried is looking on this

$\left(y\cdot\left(2x-y^{2}\right)\right)'=y'\cdot\left(2x-y^{2}\right)+y\left(2-2y\cdot y'\right)=\underset{\text{=0 for a sol}}{\underbrace{y'\cdot\left(2x-y^{2}\right)-2y}}+2y\left(2-y\cdot y'\right)$

and this

$\left(y\cdot\left(x^{3}+e^{y}\right)\right)'=y'\cdot\left(x^{3}+e^{y}\right)+y\cdot\left(3x^{2}+e^{y}\cdot y'\right)$

But i don't really know if that helps

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first equation
$$\text{(1) }\left(2x-y^{2}\right)\cdot y'=2y$$
It's far easier to use $x'=\frac {dx}{dy}$ instead

$$\left(2x-y^{2}\right)\frac {dy}{dx}=2y  \implies \left(2x-y^{2}\right)=2y\frac {dx}{dy}$$
$$(2x-y^{2})=2yx'$$
$$yx'-x=-\frac 12y^2$$
$$\frac {yx'-x}{y^2}=-\frac 12$$
$$(\frac xy)'=-\frac 12$$
Integrate simply
$$(\frac xy)=-\frac 12\int dy$$
$$\frac xy=-\frac 12y+K$$
$$\boxed {x(y)=-\frac 12y^2+Ky}$$

---

First equation can also be solved easily this way :
$$(2x-y^{2})y'=2y$$
$$2(xy'-y)=y^{2}y' \implies y-xy'=-\frac 12y^{2}y'$$
$$ \left (\frac xy\right )'=-\frac 12y'$$
Integrate
$$ \left (\frac xy\right )=-\frac 12y+K$$
Therefore
$$ x(y)=-\frac 12y^2+Ky$$

---

For the second equation
$$\text{(2) }\left(x^{3}+e^{y}\right)\cdot y'=3x^{2}$$
$$\left(x^{3}+e^{y}\right)\frac {dy}{dx}=3x^{2} \implies \left(x^{3}+e^{y}\right)=3x^{2}\frac {dx}{dy}$$
$$x^{3}+e^{y}=3x^{2}x'$$
$$x^{3}+e^{y}=(x^3)'$$
Substitute $z=x^3$
$$z+e^{y}=z' \implies z'-z=e^y$$
Multiply both sides by $e^{-y}$
$$(ze^{-y})'=1$$
$$\boxed {x^3e^{-y}-y=K}$$

Answer (score 1):

Wr6titing your first equation in the form

$$-2y(x)+(2x-y(x)^2)y'(x)=0$$
we need an integrating factor $$\mu(y)$$
and we get

$$2y\frac{d\mu(y)}{dx}-2\mu(y)=2\mu(y)$$
from here we get  $$\mu(y)=\frac{1}{y^2}$$

multiplying our equation by $\mu(y)$

$$-\frac{2}{y(x)}+\left(\frac{2x}{\mu(x)^2}-1\right)\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=0$$

so

$$f(x,y)=\int \frac{2}{y}dx=-\frac{2x}{y}+g(y)$$

to compute $g(y)$

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{2x}{y(x)^2}+\frac{dg(y)}{dy}$$

so $$g(y)=-\int dy=-y$$

and we get

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\sqrt{-8x+C_1^2}-C_1\right)$$
or

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{-8x+C_1^2}-C_1\right)$$

to Your second equation

writing

$$-3x^2+(e^{y(x)}+x^3)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

computing an integrating factor

$$-3\frac{d\mu(y)}{dy}x^2=3\mu(y)x^2$$

so $$\mu(y)=e^{\mu(y)}$$ and we get

$$-3e^{-y(x)}x^2+(e^{y(x)}x^3+1)\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=0$$

the equation is exact:

$$f(x,y)=\int -3e^{-y}x^2dx=e^{-y}x^3+g(y)$$

computing $g(y)$

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-e^{-y}x^3+g(y))=e^{-y}x^3+\frac{dg(y)}{dy}$$

so

$$g(y)=y$$
and

$$f(x,y)=-e^{-y}x^3+y$$

and the solution is given by

$$-e^{-y}x^3+y=C_1$$

Comment: Ok thank you, the temperature in Germany is to high for me!

Comment: There are some minus signs missing? You can continue to $e^{-c}x^3=(y-c)e^{y-c}$, $y=c+W(e^{-c}x^3)$.